# Bash Script If null evaluating as false when true

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I've run into my second hurdle in my journey into shell scripting. I cannot seem to get my if statement to evaluate as true for a null value. I am trying to pass an argument to the script and have the script let me know if I am missing the required variable. Unfortunately it keeps falling through to the else statement, even though it should be evaluating the variable as a null one. Here is the script:

```
if [ "$1" == "d" ]; then

        if [ -n "$2" ]; then
            echo "Please enter the local location of the files"
        else
            LOCAL=$2
            scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem $LOCAL ubuntu@54.XXX.194.202:~/test/
        fi

    else
        scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/files/binaryhustle/ ubuntu@54.XXX.194.202:~/test/
    fi
```

Here is the command I am running to execute the script:` bash copyfile.sh d

The response I get is:

`usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2`
`

Comment: ``-n`` means that the length is not zero. Did you mean ``-z``? Also use correct shebang instead of executing this script with bash. And don't forget that ``[`` is a ``test`` command, you can use ``[[ ]]`` in bash.

Comment: @Melbourne2991 And like I've said before please quote your variables (`"$LOCAL"`). If `LOCAL` gets a value that has a space on it your command would run with an error.

Comment: Great thanks, when you say use the correct shebang, do you mean the first line of the script should have the location of the shell. Also is the code I have written bash code?? or shell code, not too sure :O. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the comments, with a function added to eliminate code duplication:

```
#!/bin/bash

keyfile=~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem 
destination=ubuntu@54.XXX.194.202:~/test/
default_source=~/Dropbox/Business/aws/files/binaryhustle/

do_copy() {
    source=$1
    scp -r -i $keyfile "$source" "$destination"
}

if [ "$1" == "d" ]; then
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "Please enter the local location of the files"
    else
        do_copy "$2"
    fi
else
    do_copy "$default_source"
fi
```